# Does it sound right in English?

Tags: expressions

After being put at a crossroad

(I would say: when someone puts another in a situation that he/she has to decide what to do)

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, a "crossroad" is just *there* - something you *arrive* at, rather than being put in that position by someone else. If you want to stick with the same general type of metaphoric usage, consider [*"put in the driving seat"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+in+the+driving+seat%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (to be put in control, responsible for any decisions that need to be made).

Comment: Metaphors aren't magic; like jokes, they hafta get set up. _Crossroad_ does not presuppose "decision point", or even refer to decisions, without some guidance: _After arriving at a crossroad in our relationship / in my career / for the company's future_, etc. As for your question, no, it doesn't sound right in English; certainly not idiomatic. It's grammatical, though only barely, and it seems clear enough, if you go to the trouble of imagining the context that was left out.

Comment: It is not wrong, in any technical sense.  One could be "put" at a crossroad by being, eg, kidnapped, blindfolded, then dropped at that intersection, either literally or metaphorically.  And since you want to emphasize that person A has done this to person B, "being put at" is a reasonable phrasing -- can't think of a better one, offhand.

Comment: It sounds better with 'crossroads'. A 'crossroad' is a road that crosses another. A 'crossroads' (what you meant) is the intersection where two roads cross each other.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression is:

> After **finding themselves** at a crossroads

Comment: +1 Or *coming to a crossroads*.

Comment: Ok, but I whan to put the emphasis that one has put the other in a crosroad

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

> After being brought to a crossroads

or

> Having been brought to a crossroads

- to indicate that this choice was thrust upon them.

Answer (score -1):

CrossroadS - it cannot be a crossroad (singular)!

Comment: Actually, 'it' can:  _crossroad_ n.
1. A road that intersects another road. [AHDEL] So there are two of these things at a crossroads.

Comment: check usage, not just the word!

Comment: I was commenting on what you wrote (that's why I put 'it' in scare-quotes). I'm pointing out that your answer is not well phrased. Though I'd agree that OP should use _crossroads_ here.

Comment: "Crossroad" and "crossroads" are probably about equally common, and equally valid.  When used in the metaphorical sense I'd pick the one that tended to agree with the number of decisions to be made.